# Ubuntu Dbeaver backup database

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, dbeaver

I have `Dbeaver` installed and I have a connection to a PostgreSQL database on a remote server.
I'd like to export this database to my local PC but when I go to **Tools -> Backup database** I see an error

`Client home is not specified for connection`

What should I specify and where? I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about programming; it might be a good fit for [Database Administators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I use Windows 7, so maybe it doesn't work the same way, but it is worth a try. 
First you have to install your local postgresql server. When this is done, it's quite simple, just make a rightclick on your PostgreSQL connection and then click on "Edit Connection". Here you can choose your local client.

I must say, I've search long enough for this on my own. Hope it helps.

And it is my first post, so sorry if I did something wrong.

Screenshot Server Connection:

[image: Screenshot Server Connection]

Screenshot Edit Settings:

[image: Screenshot Edit Settings]

Comment: but for me in the local client : "/usr/bin/" working fine. Ubunt 16.04

Comment: I have struggled a lot with this error on macOS!
- I have installed mysql via homebrew, and I did not know what folder to set as Client Home.
Eventually this worked for me:
`/usr/local/opt/mysql`

Comment: How to get local postgresql??

Comment: In macOS i found it under /usr/local , my installation it was done with Postgres.app

Comment: local client : "/usr/bin/" worked for Ubuntu 19.04 and mysql version 8.0 as well

Answer (score 23):

I found this solution using ubuntu linux:

look for `pg_dump` running this command as root

```
find / -name "pg_dump"
```

in my case, the relevant result is `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump`

Then, in "Connection Settings" as other answers here, click on "browse" and browse to  `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump` or the location resulted on the previous step.

Comment: This was my exact issue too. When running Ubuntu 20.4 and Postres 12

Comment: what if the postgres is in docker container? sorry its late I Know. hope someone could help. thank you

Comment: @JackySupit it is the same, I'm actually using a docker container.

Comment: If you download just by doing `sudo apt install dbeaver-ce`, you will not be able to set this path (dbeaver will not get write access to any bin directories). So, just properly follow the instructions given here https://dbeaver.io/download/ and you will be able to follow above answer.

Answer (score 19):

## MAC specific answer

I ran into the same issue. Essentially, DBeaver needs to know where the postgresql bin is located. It contains things like `pg_dump` which the backup tool depends on. If you don't have PostgreSQL installed, then I'd recommend installing via: [postgresapp.com](https://postgresapp.com/)

For version 11, as of this comment, the lib installation will be located here: `/Applications/Postgres.app/contents/versions/11/bin`.

Versions installed with `brew` are located in `/usr/local/bin/postgres`.

So within DBeaver you'll want to edit the **DB connection** properties to reflect the below screenshot. You'll be prompted to reconnect to your DB, but then you should be good to go.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: This way it works too, so you can use the "/usr/bin/"  directory or this. I do not know if is there a difference.

Comment: another mac spesific answer;
You could also use homebrew to install libpq.

brew install libpq
This would give you psql, pg_dump and a whole bunch of other client utilities without installing Postgres.


if use zsh:

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
if use bash:

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 15):

### Linux Specific Answer

- Install PostgreSQL client locally
- Open the terminal and type `which pg_dump` and it will return something like `/usr/bin/pg_dump`
- In local client settings select browse and add the folder from the previous step. In my case it was `/usr/bin/`. Wait a few seconds it will detect the driver

Comment: ```sudo apt install postgresql-client-common``` might be required if pg_dump not found and ```sudo apt-get install postgresql-client``` for default client

Answer (score 4):

For Mac,

Right click on your connection -> "**Edit Connection**". (see image)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp8Jg.png)

For local client, click **browse** (see below)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONr36.png)

To see hidden file and folders, press "**cmd + shift + .**" Now you can browse to PG bin folder. Path will be added to local client. 
After adding, select that path and you will see id, path, and name will be populated (see image)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4g4F.png)

Answer (score 2):

Postgres SQL installed using Enterprise DB installer on Mac OS, `pg_restore` will be located in `/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin`..

So select this location in DBeaver

[image: screenshot for reference]

It worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04,Add Local Client value as '/user' (in Connection settings -->main)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.